# I don't know which one is correct to use: they will be redirected or they redirect?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I built a sentence but i don't know which one is better to use based on its previous sentence:

If/when they click on it,

> they **will be redirected** to another page.
>
> **or**
> they **redirect** to another page.

I don't know if I use will be redirected or only redirect?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question depends on the antecedent to the pronoun "they"

> If users look for information page xyz.com  they will be redirected to
> another page.

> Web searches that send users to xyz.com will redirect to another page.

So the first is correct in your case.

Answer (score 1):

*redirect* is a transitive verb meaning it needs an object.

> they will be redirected.

implies an agent who redirects them somewhere. The agent is your application (your server I suppose).

> they will be redirected (by the application).

which can be omitted since the context makes it clear.

Compare it with a sentence put in the active voice.

> The application will redirect them to another page.

Your second sentence is not grammatically correct.

> They redirect (what?) to another page.

Comment: Well, it *could* be grammatically correct, in a different sentence.  The website's code *redirects* users to another page, and the users *are redirected*.  You're right, though, Vahid's sentence needs "are redirected".  Straightforward question of subject vs. object.